# I Made A Background For my App, But Now It Won't Run

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background

I just set up a background for this app I'm making, but now it won't run. It was working before I assigned the background. I was wondering if someone could help me with this. Maybe I'm supposed to have some java code with it as well?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundhdpi" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="Enter Your Bill"
            android:textSize="18dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculateTip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bill"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Calculate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tipOwed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bill"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="123dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="Time to Tip"
            android:textColor="#2c6f37"
            android:textSize="35dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Logcat outup would be usefull ;-)

Comment: I don't think itll help. My emulator never finished loading :/. I just use my phone to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the background is in res/drawable it shouldn't cause any crashing issues. There is no Java that needs to be associated with setting a background that way. Is there an error in the logcat?

(I would leave this as a comment but I don't have enough rep to do so)

Comment: Even if you deploy to your phone the crash log will show up in logcat

Comment: I figured out the problem. It had something to do with the manifest but thank you for your help :)